# Update custom order item meta in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I am missing something. I have seen several articles about how to update an items meta data but I can't get any one of them to work. I need to get the item_id but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
$your_phone = $item->get_meta('dinner_phone'); // 1115559999
$update_phone = wdc_format_phone($your_phone); // comes back (111) 555-9999

wc_update_order_item_meta($item_id,'dinner_phone', $update_phone); //I want to update with new format

$new_phone = $item->get_meta('dinner_phone'); // doesn't work I still get 1115559999
```

I have tried to pull the Item_id by the following

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    $item_id = $item['item_id'];
    break;
}
```

Also tried this

```
    foreach ($items as $key => $product ) {
      $item_id = $key;
   }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get an item meta then edit that meta?

Comment: Are you referring to a custom field inside a product? or an order?

Comment: You'll need to give more information and show more of your code. I believe you can't call `get_meta()` on an item, but in your example you say this returns `1115559999`. So that makes me wonder if you really mean item meta, and not product meta. There is quite the difference there. Could you provide us with the full function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will use the following from an existing WC_Order Object `$order` variable:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item-id => $item ) {
    $dinner_phone   = $item->get_meta('dinner_phone'); // 1115559999
    if ( ! empty( $dinner_phone ) ) {
        $formatted_diner_phone = wdc_format_phone( $dinner_phone ); // comes back (111) 555-9999

        $item->update_meta_data('dinner_phone', $formatted_diner_phone);

        $item->save(); // Save item

        $new_phone = $item->get_meta('dinner_phone');
        echo $new_phone; // Check that items is updated
    }
    $order->calculate_totals(); // Recalculate Order totals and save
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Yes this worked. I need to add $dinner_phone to the empty() function but  other than that it worked perfectly. I was missing the line $item->save()